# Measuring one register of the state $\frac{1}{2^{m}} \sum_{x}\sum_{k} (-1) ^ {x\cdot k} |k\rangle |f(x)\rangle$

Tags: quantum-state, measurement, probability

I'm reading the [article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/236) which contains lemma 1. Its proof contains the statement, that probability of getting $|0\rangle$ (denote it as $\text{Pr}\left[|0\rangle\right]$) after measuring the first register of state $\frac{1}{2^{m}} |0\rangle \sum_{x} |f(x)\rangle + \frac{1}{2^{m}} \sum_{x}\sum_{k\ne0} (-1) ^ {x\cdot k} |k\rangle |f(x)\rangle$ equals $\frac{1}{2^{2m}} \sum_{y} \left|f^{-1}(y)\right|^{2}$, where $f:\{0,1\}^m\to\{0,1\}^n$.

It is uncear, why there is a square of $f$'s preimage cardinality.
Doesn't the probability $\text{Pr}\left[|0\rangle\right]$ just equal $\frac{1}{2^{m}}$?

We consider the only terms $\frac{1}{2^{m}} |0\rangle \sum_{x} |f(x)\rangle = \frac{1}{2^{m}} \sum_{x} |0\rangle |f(x)\rangle$ since the rest ones are canceled out by $\langle0|k\rangle = 0$ for non-zero $k$.

We have: $\text{Pr}\left[|0\rangle\right] = \frac{1}{2^{2m}}\langle0, f(0...0)|0, f(0...0)\rangle + ... + \frac{1}{2^{2m}}\langle0, f(1...1)|0, f(1...1)\rangle = \frac{1}{2^{2m}} + ... + \frac{1}{2^{2m}} = \frac{1}{2^{2m}}\cdot{2^{m}}=\frac{1}{2^{m}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your state before measurement is
$$
|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{2^m}|0\rangle\sum_x|f(x)\rangle+\frac{1}{2^m}\sum_x\sum_{k\neq 0}(-1)^{x\cdot k}|k\rangle|f(x)\rangle.
$$
How do we calculate the probability of getting the 0 result?
$$
p_0=\langle\psi|(|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I)|\psi\rangle.
$$
So, if you calculate this, you'll get
$$
p_0=\frac{1}{2^{2m}}\sum_{x,z}\langle f(z)|f(x)\rangle.
$$
Now, as we sum over all possible values of $z$, the question is how many times does a value $y=f(x)$ appear? $|f^{-1}(y)|$ (I think this is what you missed in your calculation). Hence, we have (I'm being a little loose with notation)
$$
p_0=\frac{1}{2^{2m}}\sum_x|f^{-1}(y)|.
$$
Now, we could instead just sum over the distinct values $y=f(x)$. Each value $y$ is repeated $|f^{-1}(y)|$ times in the sum over $x$. Hence,
$$
p_0=\frac{1}{2^{2m}}\sum_{y}|f^{-1}(y)|^2.
$$

Comment: That's indeed what I missed. Thanks for a good explanation!